# concatinate rows with the same id in the same table into one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle table that contains transfers of items between stores the table shape is like this

|itemid |   storeid |   transdate|  transtype|

|:---- |:------:| -----:|-----:|

|1  |2  |1/1/2023|  2|

|1  |3  |2/1/2023|  3|

|2  |3  |1/2/2023|  2|

|2  |4  |2/2/2023|  3|

|2  |3  |3/1/2023|  1|

I want to put all rows for a specific id into one row no matter how many transfers are
The output should be like this

| itemid | officeid | transdate | transtype | officeid transdate | transtype | officeid transdate | transtype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1/1/2023 | 2 | 3 | 2/1/2023 | 3 |  |
| 2 | 3 | 1/2/2023 | 2 | 4 | 2/2/2023 | 3 | 3 | 1 |

Comment: You need to look at GROUP BY and use aggregate functions on the columns you want to collapse into a single row.